# How can I use Dapper's QueryMultiple with a stored procedure, but with a different parameter value each time?

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I want to call a stored procedure in bulk with Dapper.  Each call will return a different set of results, so I was using QueryMultiple.  If I create the parameters like this:

```
    var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
    // The stored proc accepts a single integer, but I want to pass multiple so each call had a new value.
    parameters.Add("LookupID", lookupIds); 

    var resultSet = connection.QueryMultiple("SPName", parameters, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

I get an error that the stored procedure has too many arguments specified.  So how else can I accomplish this?

Comment: I think the main idea with QueryMultiple is that the stored procedure returns multiple resultsets.  If you wanted to query with different parameter definitions, define multiple procs, and call each directly with async/await.

Answer (score 1):

`QueryMultiple` is about the results, not the inputs. To do what you want, you need to call the SP lots of times. Which you can do either via a simple `foreach` loop yourself, or many (not all) of the dapper methods will allow a convenience method by passing in an `IEnumerable<T>` as the outermost object, for example:

```
int[] ids = ...
var args = ids.Select(id => new { id, val = "ABC" });
db.Execute("whatever", args);
```

Which will execute the SQL once per item passing in `@id` and `@val` for each. In the case of the `async` API this can also be combined with MARS to remove the cost of latency between calls, but this is opt-in because MARS is not a default option.

Alternatively, you could write a new wrapper SP that takes a single parameter and splits it (the new `string_split` would be ideal), and do the loop at the server.

Comment: Going to and fro to call same SP for multiple parameters is certainly for a pro performance approach, preferable would be pass a TVP, where each row is a combination of parameters for a given output, needn't even do the string parsing, as suggested